# Sum of roots of a trigonometric equation

Tags: output-formatting, trigonometry

The equation $$ \sin x + \sqrt{3} \cos x  = 1,$$ 
where $x \in [-2\pi, 2\pi]$ has four roots $-\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$, $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $\dfrac{11\pi}{6}$. Sum of  roots of the given equation is $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$.  How do I tell Mathematica to do that?

I tried

```
Solve[{Sin[x] + Sqrt[3]*Cos[x] == 1, -2*π <= x <= 2*π}, {x}]
```

**edit** from comment

I repaired the given equation to

```
Solve[{Sin[x] + Sqrt[3]Cos[x] == 1, -2[Pi] <= x <= 2*[Pi]}, {x}]
```

and used

```
Simplify@Total[ x /. Solve[{Sin[x] + Sqrt[3] Cos[x] == 2, -2 Pi <= x <= 2 Pi}, {x}]],
```

and I got the answer

```
-4 [Pi] + 8 ArcTan[1/(2 + Sqrt[3])].
```

How do I get the answer -((5 [Pi])/3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way :

```
Total[Reduce[Sin[x] + Sqrt[3] Cos[x] == 1 && -2 \[Pi] <= x <= 2 \[Pi], x] /. Or -> List /. x == rhs_ -> rhs] // Simplify

(* (2 \[Pi])/3 *)
```

Comment: Thank Artes very much.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your added question: try `FullSimplify[]`:

```
FullSimplify @ Total[ DeleteDuplicates[ x 
      /. Solve[{Sin[x] + Sqrt[3] Cos[x] == 2, -2 Pi <= x <= 2 Pi}, {x}]]]
```

returns

> $ \dfrac{-5 \pi}{3}$

Like *Artes* says you need `DeleteDuplicates[]` because of the multiple roots.

From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullSimplify.html):

> **FullSimplify**[*expr*]
>   tries a wide range of transformations on *expr* involving elementary and special functions, and returns the simplest form it finds.